# How should I pass 2 test groups to karate: 1 ignore group and 1 include group

Tags: karate

Here is my scenario.

I setup a Karate Java runner test method like this:

```
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:features")
    .outputCucumberJson(true)
    .tags(GLOBAL_INCLUDE, GLOBAL_IGNORE_ALL)
    .parallel(5);
```

And I setup variables for test groups like so:

```
static final String REGRESSION_TAG = "regression";
static final String GLOBAL_IGNORE_ALL = "~@ignore";
static final String GLOBAL_INCLUDE = "@" + System.getProperty("test.type", REGRESSION_TAG).toLowerCase();
```

But the above configuration FAILS to ignore the `@ignore` tags.

The only way I could get it to work was by adding the deprecated test runner annotation like so:

```
@KarateOptions(tags = {"~@ignore"} )
public class RunIT {
...
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:features")
    .outputCucumberJson(true)
    .tags(GLOBAL_INCLUDE)
    .parallel(5);
...
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?   Just trying to pass 2 tags in a AND-condition style:    all the regression tests minus the ignore tests.

Version: Karate 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this has changed in Karate 1.1.0.RC3 onwards: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases/tag/v1.1.0.RC3 (read the release notes)

And maybe you needed to do `.tags(GLOBAL_INCLUDE + "," + GLOBAL_IGNORE_ALL)` - there are subtle differences for "AND" vs "OR".

So try that, and follow this process if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: interesting thing.  turns out that the cause of the question I had above was that I had the `@RunWith(Karate.class)` annotation on my test runner class. As soon as I removed that, all the sudden the test tags work as I expect!   That took me forever to figure it out,  thanks to your tags example runner, which gave me the hint.